# ssrs parameter using lookup

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, lookup

I'm trying to retrive multiple values of the same row of a dataset.
I have a first parameter that uses the dataset called "getCycleVie"
from there I retrive the row identifier of the dataset.
I have to retrive the two other values of that row to use for a parameter in another dataset, the `dtdebut` and the `dtfin`
This works in a textbox

`=Lookup(
    Trim(Parameters!CycleVie.Value)
    ,Trim(Fields!cyclevie.Value)
    ,Fields!dtdebut.Value
    ,"getCycleVie"
)`

however when I add it as the default value of a parameter or if I add it as a paramter in a dataset I get the following error
`Une expression de la propriété Value utilisée pour le paramètre de rapport de l'objet 'dtdebut' fait référence à un champ.  Les champs ne peuvent pas être utilisés dans les expressions de paramètre de rapport.`
 which roughly translates to `an expression of the property value used for the report parameter  object 'dtdebut' is referencing a field. a field cannot be used in the parameter expressions of the report`

I don't necessarily need my lookup, all I need is to retreive multiple values of the same row of a dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the lookup is the problem but that you want to use it in a parameter. You're probably going to need to create a new dataset and base it off your first parameter.

Your new dataset would look something like:

```
SELECT dtdebut 
FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE cyclevie = @CycleVie
```

Then use the dataset result for your other parameter.

Here's more info on Cascading Parameters - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337498(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I know that this would solve my problem but my source is a stored procedure so if I do that it would force me to change the stored procedure which I cannot

Comment: Since you can't change your SP, you can use a FILTER on the dataset instead. Click on the Dataset Properties' **Filter** tab and select the cyclevie field in the **Expression** box and change **Value** to your parameter (@CycleVie).

Comment: alright, I'll give you the answer because of "I don't think the lookup is the problem but that you want to use it in a parameter."
I knew of the other solutions but they are really not ideal since it forces me to create a dataset each time I want to retrieve more than one peice of data in a row.

Comment: What I found is that the parameter and the field in the data set that you lookup on need to have the same data type. So if your Fields!cyclevie.Value is integer but Parameters!CycleVie is Text, the lookup won't work. Changing the data type of the parameter to Integer fixed similar issue for me